# Доработать регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение для разбора навигации.

Блок навигации может может менять от такого:

```
    <a href="/">HOME</a> /  

    Deep 1

</div>
```

До такого:

```
<div id="bread-crumbs">

    <a href="/">HOME</a> /  

    <a href="/deep1">Deep 1</a> /

    <a href="/deep2">Deep 2</a> /

    TFXF2X - FDS<34>0C500 (78-12)

</div>
```

Выдачу хочу получить такую для первого варианта

```
HOME Deep 1
```

Такую для второго

```
HOME Deep 1 Deep 2 TFXF2X - FDS<34>0C500 (78-12)
```

Смог разобраться до такого варианта https://regex101.com/r/J1Lur7/3/
Далее прошу помощи - не могу обернуть это в

```
<div id="bread-crumbs"></div>
```

и достать последнюю строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно конечно использовать что-то вроде https://regex101.com/r/cfR2d9/4

```
/<a\s.*?>(.*?)<\/a>|\/\s+([^\n]+)\s+<\/div>/gs
```

но возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону парсеров DOM на php.